# Color until line break (without luatex)

Tags: macros, color

I need to create a command based on `\color` with a result like this 
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% \def\costumcol#1{.....}

\begin{document}

sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text 
sample text sample text sample text \costumcol{red} sample text 
sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text 

\hsize=.8\textwidth

sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text 
sample text sample text sample text \costumcol{red} sample text 
sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this really isn't what the the color package was designed to do and isn't entirely robust but...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\def\costumcol#1{{\let\aftergroup\@gobble\color{#1}}\vadjust{\reset@color}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text 
sample text sample text sample text \costumcol{red} sample text 
sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text 

\hsize=.8\textwidth

sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text 
sample text sample text sample text \costumcol{red} sample text 
sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text 

\end{document}
```

Comment: and now in rtl mode (which the question is probably about ...).

Comment: Yes exactly @UlrikeFischer  :)

Comment: @SalimBou rtl mode will be completely different (but that would be a **different question**)

Comment: @David Would you please explain how it works?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle how it  could be doable with rtl ?

Comment: @AlexG it sets color disabling the reset that happens at the end of a group (so that is a colour push)  then it places a color pop in vadjust (so after the current line instead of the one that would have been adde by \aftergroup)

Comment: @SalimBou it depends what the question is (and you haven't asked it yet)  in particlular it depends on how the colour changes and language direction changes are related. ther is no general answer to all possible similar questions. If you post a question someone may be able to answer.

Comment: I am too slow-witted to follow, @David :(. Is `\vadjust` a macro that is executed at every line break?

Comment: it's a tex primitive it inserts a node into the horizontal list that is migrated into the vertical list by tex's basic linebreaker and inserted at the same time baselineskip is inserted (and just after the current line box and before baselineskip)  @AlexG (so it is like a footnote in that it is executed at the point it is encountered but is saved and re-inserted at a different point)

Comment: Thank you. And what is the purpose of `\let` and `\@gobble`? It looks as if `\let` is used to overwrite `\aftergroup` with the meaning `\@gobble` which looks strange to me.

Comment: @AlexG `\color{red}` is `\system-specific-command-to-push-color{red}\aftergroup\reset@color`  where `\reset@color` is  `\system-specific-command-to-pop-color`  so by making `\aftergroup` be `\@gobble` the `\reset@color` is lost and the macro can then insert one via `\vadjust` instead of at the end of the group

Comment: Incredible! But must be true ;-). I think I got it, more or less. Nevertheless, it is interesting that pushing the colour survives the end of the group within which it was issued.

Comment: @AlexG color works at the back end (in classic tex in the dvi driver) way after tex groups have no meaning.  the whole "colour safe groups" story is a ruse we invented to allow this `\aftergroup` trick to restore colours at the end of a group so that there is a semblance of colour commands working like font commands and obeying tex grouping.