# Make rest of a line bold

Tags: line-breaking, bold

Referring to
[Color until line break (without luatex)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472929/color-until-line-break-without-luatex/472933#472933)

where a solution was given to colorize the rest of line (from any point upto its end), I tried to put the text in e.g. bold rather than coloring it, to no avail.

As my TeX knowledge is not profound enough, I ask:
Can some kind TeX-guru give me a solution for that?

Regards
Jack

Comment: there is  basically no way to do that for an automatic line break

Comment: specific cases may possibly be feasible, do you really need the general case where you start a line in normal weight, then start bold somewhere and keep bold until the end of the line then revert to normal weight at the automatic line break?

Comment: Well, the first character is a dropcapped one and the rest of the line should be bold (or in smallcaps or ...)

Comment: I posted an answer but in any real document I would do this by hand, just use `lettrine` or another standard drop cap package and just put enough text in to its argument that the styled text just fills the first line, compared to the rest of the document editing a slight amount of hand work here seems reasonable

Comment: Yes, I know. And that's the way I do it up to now. But I have to create the same document in several pointsizes and paper widths. An then it becomes a real pain in the xxx. So I tried to automate this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change font at an automatic line break, as fonts need to be chosen, and the text set, before linebreak points are  chosen.

However you can (perhaps) set the text twice, with and without  the font change, and then re-constitute the desired paragraph.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\setbox0\vbox{{%
    Medium text here
\fontseries{b}\selectfont% b not bx so line breaking (hopefully) not affected
bold starts here and goes on \ldots
the first line of the paragraph has several lines and may have\[math\]
and other stuff, the line break may happen at a hyphenation point.
}}



\setbox2\vbox{{%
    Medium text here
bold starts here and goes on \ldots
the first line of the paragraph has several lines and may have\[math\]
and other stuff, the line break may happen at a hyphenation point.
}}


{\vbadness=10000
\setbox4=\vsplit0 to \ht\strutbox
\setbox6=\vsplit2 to \ht\strutbox

\box4
\nointerlineskip
\box2
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you David. When I use the libertine font (as I almost always do for my writings) then the graph part of para-graph has disappeared. Does package libertine do something nasty?

Comment: This relies on the `b` font having exactly the same width as normal weight so the line breaking is the same,  that is true for computer modern (unlike the usual `bx` bold)  but is not guaranteed, put `\copy0  \copy2` before the vbadness group so you see the two original settings, if the line breaking is different then this isn't really fixable. @Jack

Comment: OK, thank you David, for explaining